# Running python script in colab very slow as compared to same code run on directly colab in notebook

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

Recently I was trying to test my model which i already trained. Initially I was using Google colab notebook to write code because of it's interactive features, once I was done writing code and I was getting satisfactory results, it took around 2.5 hr to give final output. After that what I wanted was to transfer the notebook code to .py script, I did that with little bit of modification, saved it in gdrive, and then used command `!python test.py`. now it took me more than 4.5 hr to get the final output, can any one explain why does colab take so much time when trying to run the python script from gdrive while compared to the same code as used in notebook

Comment: Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe? As-is, there's not enough detail in the question to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would add time calculation to every step I doubt that takes time and see which step in your whole program takes the time.

```
      a1 = time.time()
      //your code step
      print(time.time() - a1)
```

This will give you the time for each step and you can see which one is taking a long time.

Operations to check.
1. object creation in loops
2. read/write operation to Gdrive

Once you find the problem-causing piece of code, you may change it.

Answer (score 0):

Well it can be because of the fact that colab is retrieving the data from gdrive and then might be again writing in gdrive which will of ofcourse take time i guess